# MariaDB, PBXT and mysterious query results

Tags: mariadb, pbxt

First of all, here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `outlet_tags` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `importer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `outlet_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_set` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_details` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_report_outlet_tags_1` (`importer_id`),
  KEY `fk_report_outlet_tags_2` (`outlet_id`),
  KEY `outlet_tag_set` (`tag_set`),
  KEY `outlet_tag_type` (`tag_type`),
  KEY `outlet_tag_details` (`tag_details`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_report_outlet_tags_1` FOREIGN KEY (`importer_id`) REFERENCES `importers` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_report_outlet_tags_2` FOREIGN KEY (`outlet_id`) REFERENCES `outlets` (`id`)
) ENGINE=PBXT DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Can anyone shed any light on why the field values change depending upon the conditions used in the following queries? It doesn't happen if the engine is Maria.

```
select * from outlet_tags where code=1503 and outlet_id=407 limit 3;
+------+-------------+-----------+------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| id   | importer_id | outlet_id | code | postcode | tag_set | tag_type        | tag_details    |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
|  222 |           1 |       407 | 1503 | XXX XXX  | outlet  | Make up         | Make up        |
|  675 |           1 |       407 | 1503 | XXX XXX  | outlet  | Approved Status | Approved       |
| 1619 |           1 |       407 | 1503 | XXX XXX  | outlet  | Retail Area     | No Retail Area |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from outlet_tags where code=1503 and importer_id=1 limit 3;
+------+-------------+-----------+------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
| id   | importer_id | outlet_id | code | postcode | tag_set | tag_type        | tag_details    |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
|  222 |           1 |       407 | 1503 | XXX XXX  | outlet  | Make up         | Make up        |
|  675 |           1 |       407 | 1503 | XXX XXX  | outlet  | Approved Status | Approved       |
| 1619 |           1 |       407 | 1503 | XXX XXX  | outlet  | Retail Area     | No Retail Area |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+----------+---------+-----------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from outlet_tags where importer_id=1 and outlet_id=407 limit 3;
+------+-------------+-----------+------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id   | importer_id | outlet_id | code | postcode | tag_set | tag_type | tag_details |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  222 |           1 |       407 | 1503 | NULL     | NULL    | NULL     | NULL        |
|  675 |           1 |       407 | 1503 | NULL     | NULL    | NULL     | NULL        |
| 1619 |           1 |       407 | 1503 | NULL     | NULL    | NULL     | NULL        |
+------+-------------+-----------+------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Update*: as of MariaDB 5.5 [PBXT was dropped as a storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pbxt-storage-engine/)

Comment: Does anyone think that it could have been bad index data causing the NULL values? The third query is the only one to use only indexed fields in the WHERE condition

Answer (score 1):

Try using an ORDER BY with the queries.

Different engines may return rows in different order depending on how the rows are retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this one back from the dead! I'm not sure that I understand your comment though. The rows that are returned by the 3 queries have matching PKs and thus are the same rows, yet the third query has NULL values where the other 2 have valid data.